# Tasked called first after finishing the task before

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to populate an HTML snippet(you can see it below). SO I want to achieve this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/941jes7svcyusmf/example.PNG?dl=0 So I wrote this js Code(note: I work with firebase) to populate the div and than fill in the values:

```
members.forEach(el => {
              console.log(el)

              table_number++;
              console.log("forEachMember" + table_number);

              const html = populateTable("member_name" + table_number, "layout_table" + table_number);
              document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

              db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                    const data = doc.data();

                    addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);

                });
              });
            })
```

And here is the function where I add the values to the table:

```
function addToTable(table_name, subject, mdl, klu) {

  var subject_name = getSubjectByNumber(subject);
  var short_subject = getSubjectShortByNumber(subject);

      //Zeile erstellen

      console.log("addToTable" + table_name);

      var y = document.createElement([short_subject]);
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);
      document.getElementById([table_name]).appendChild(y);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var cE = document.createElement("TD");
      var tE = document.createTextNode([subject_name]);
      cE.appendChild(tE);
      y.appendChild(cE);

      var a = document.createElement("TD");
      var b = document.createTextNode([mdl]);
      a.appendChild(b);
      y.appendChild(a);

      var c = document.createElement("TD");
      var d = document.createTextNode([klu]);
      c.appendChild(d);
      y.appendChild(c);


      document.getElementById(table_name).appendChild(y);
}
```

But my problem is that there are only the tables but not filled in with rows and columns. (short with information) So I get this Error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. So the table is there but it can not find it. So I started to use console.log(); It seems like the `members.forEach(el => {` task runs to finish and than first the `db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {` task starts. And than the var table_number is null. But why and how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
@israelss mentioned it is an issue with the asynchronous task of Firebase. But how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since JavaScript is asynchronous the loop won’t wait for the mongo query to start , so, you have to first run the mongo query and inside its promise do the loop.
I’m on my phone so it’s kind of annoying to type code but I’m pretty sure that’s the problem

Comment: Can you please give me a code example when you back to your laptop? Because it would be very interesting how to fix this. :)

Comment: It won't let me add it as a comment, so I added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            const data = doc.data();
            members.forEach(el => {
                console.log(el)

                table_number++;
                console.log("forEachMember" + table_number);

                const html = populateTable("member_name" + table_number, "layout_table" + table_number);
                document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
                addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);

              })  
        });
      });
```

The thing is that first you have to do the most time consuming task, in this case the db query, then do the rest.
Since Javascript is asynchronous it means that it won't wait for one instruction to complete before moving on to the next one, it will try to do all of them at the same time, unless you uses promises.

Comment: Hey sorry for my late reply. But exactly this is the clue. In the first line of your code: `db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {` . The "el" is not defined. Because I initialize the "el" with this line which comes later first here: `members.forEach(el => {`

Comment: Hope you can help me out even the late reply